# Распорядитель по общежитию среди студентов

Tags: названия, терминология

Среди студентов в общежитии выделяют распорядителя, который отвечает за порядок, дисциплину, выступает с вопросами от студентов в качестве представителя и так далее. Как называется эта деятельность, как называют такого человека и можно ли назвать занимаемое им место должностью?

Comment: Староста, например.

Answer (score 1):

Такая деятельность - это самоуправление.  Студсовет – это «орган студенческого самоуправления, отражающий проблемы и интересы студенческой аудитории и осуществляющий связь студентов с руководством вуза».

**Студенческий совет общежития** состоит из старосты общежития, старост этажей (крыльев), профорга общежития и студенческой группы охраны общественного порядка (СГОП).

Распорядитель - это всё-таки староста общежития. И да, это должность.

Подробнее -  http://vladmolod.al.ru/text/studsovet.htm